# I would like to add a backgound image

Tags: html, background, spiceworks

I have the page exactly like I would like it to look. Now looking at it i wish I would have added a background image. Is there a simple way around this. I know the code may look a little funny but this is how Spiceworks corrects the code.

```html
<div style="text-align: center;">
<p style="font-size: 30px;">&nbsp;</p>

<p style="font-size: 30px;"><span style="color:rgb(0, 128, 0)"><strong>WELCOME TO PARK CITY CREDIT UNION&rsquo;s I.T. TICKET SYSTEM!</strong></span></p>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<p><span style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0)"><strong>Please do not email or chat, if you do so, you will be directed to open a ticket!</strong></span></p>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<p><strong>NEED IMMEDIATE ASSISTANCE and unable to reach I.T.??</strong> <strong>Call Locknet 1-877-408-1656&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></p>

<p><em>Note - Any tickets submitted after 4:00 PM may not get a response until the next business day</em>.</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<p style="font-size: 17px;"><strong>&nbsp;The Ticket System is a new platform to better serve you as well as enable a more efficient way to support your IT needs in an appropriate prioritized order.</strong></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p style="font-size: 15px;"><strong><span style="text-decoration:underline">NEED HELP? We are here for you!</span></strong></p>

<p style="font-size: 14px;">Click on the <em>&ldquo;New Ticket&rdquo;</em>&nbsp; Tab and create your ticket. If your ticket has not been started/resolved within 3 hours, please contact IT.</p>

<hr />
<p style="font-size: 15px;"><span style="text-decoration:underline"><strong><em>How do I know my ticket came through?</em></strong></span></p>

<p style="font-size: 14px;">- You will receive an email from <em>spiceworks@parkcitycu.org</em></p>

<p style="font-size: 14px;">-You will receive a second email letting you know who is working on your ticket</p>

<p style="font-size: 14px;">- You may recieve a phone call if your ticket requires follow up</p>

<hr />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code (and corrected a spelling mistake). Pretty simple fix:

```html
<body style="background-image: url(http://lorempixel.com/1024/1024/); background-repeat: no-repeat; background-size: cover;">

<div style="text-align: center;">
<p style="font-size: 30px;">&nbsp;</p>

<p style="font-size: 30px;"><span style="color:rgb(0, 128, 0)"><strong>WELCOME TO PARK CITY CREDIT UNION&rsquo;s I.T. TICKET SYSTEM!</strong></span></p>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<p><span style="color:rgb(0, 0, 0)"><strong>Please do not email or chat, if you do so, you will be directed to open a ticket!</strong></span></p>
</div>

<div style="text-align: center;">
<p><strong>NEED IMMEDIATE ASSISTANCE and unable to reach I.T.??</strong> <strong>Call Locknet 1-877-408-1656&nbsp;&nbsp;</strong></p>

<p><em>Note - Any tickets submitted after 4:00 PM may not get a response until the next business day</em>.</p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>

<p style="font-size: 17px;"><strong>&nbsp;The Ticket System is a new platform to better serve you as well as enable a more efficient way to support your IT needs in an appropriate prioritized order.</strong></p>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

<p style="font-size: 15px;"><strong><span style="text-decoration:underline">NEED HELP? We are here for you!</span></strong></p>

<p style="font-size: 14px;">Click on the <em>&ldquo;New Ticket&rdquo;</em>&nbsp; Tab and create your ticket. If your ticket has not been started/resolved within 3 hours, please contact IT.</p>

<hr />
<p style="font-size: 15px;"><span style="text-decoration:underline"><strong><em>How do I know my ticket came through?</em></strong></span></p>

<p style="font-size: 14px;">- You will receive an email from <em>spiceworks@parkcitycu.org</em></p>

<p style="font-size: 14px;">-You will receive a second email letting you know who is working on your ticket</p>

<p style="font-size: 14px;">- You may receive a phone call if your ticket requires follow up</p>

</body>
```

You need to change the image, obviously, but this code has a background image for you. Also, I would suggest you format the code differently, because the way it is currently formatting is a little hard to read. If you're going to be doing programming for the web (HTML, CSS, Javascript, etc), I recommend you use the Brackets IDE. It's not for formatting but I love it.

Anyways, GLHF!

Comment: I completely understand what your saying but it HAS to be formatted this way. Otherwise the system im using cant read it. I have found one way to get a background image but that requires css ill post what it looks like. this works but i cant get words in correct spots ---> https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_image_text.asp

Comment: @user99987 I changed the code formatting. Does it work with your system now?

Comment: ill test this first thing in the morning thanks. I used brackets when i was in web design 1 i like that program a lot. thanks for bringing it up. At work I use Notepad++ and codepen.io for testing now i have to put brackets into my everyday :)

Comment: @user99987 you should mark the post as answered so that people know it's solved.

Answer (score 0):

You should use CSS to set a background image.

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url("BACKGROUND_IMAGE_URL_HERE");
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it on the whole page you wish to add the background image? If yes, You should use CSS to set a background image:

```
<style>
    body {
        background-image: url("IMAGE-PATH-HERE");
    }
</style>
```

IMAGE-PATH-HERE should point to your image file. For example, you can copy the image to the same folder where the HTML file is, and specify the image name and extension - e.g.

```
<style>
    body{
        background-image:url("myimage.jpg");
    } 
</style>
```

If the image is on a separate folder/directory, then specify the directory path as well - e.g.

```
<style>
    body{
        background-image:url("assets/myimage.jpg");
    } 
</style>
```

Hope this helps